# iOS QuickLook add custom buttons

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, quicklook

I'm using the iOS QuickLook framework in a project and a client request is to add an Email button into the Actions menu, alongside the available actions already present.

Example: Email, Print, Open In...

Is there a way to do this?  I was thinking setToolBarItems or something similiar but I don't want to replace default actions.

Thanks SO!